# laravel 5.4 : Image file not uploaded on the aws server

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

When i work on locally upload image on folder works perfect but when i try to upload image on amazon web server file not uploaded and back with same page.Is there any problem with my code ?

Here is my controller function to save data :

```
 // CountryController
 public function save(Request $request) {
    try {
        $file = $request->file('flag_image');
        $this->validate($request, Country::rules());
        //$request->validate(Country::rules());

        /*Image Upload code*/
        If(Input::hasFile('flag_image')){
            $file = Input::file('flag_image');
            $destinationPath = public_path(). '/images/admin/country/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $image = time().$filename;
            $file->move($destinationPath, $image);
            $imgpath = 'images/admin/country/'.$image;
        }
        if($file !="") {
            $request->merge(['flag_image' => $imgpath]);
        }
        /*Image Upload code end*/

        $country = Country::saveOrUpdate($request);
        if($file !="") {
            $country->flag_image = $imgpath;
            $country->save();
        }

        if($country !== false) {
            return redirect()->route('lists-country')->with('success', trans('Country data added successfully.!!'));
        } else {
            return back()->with('error', "Unable to save country data.!!")->withInput();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return back()->with('error', "Unable to save country data.!!")->withInput();
    }
}
```

And my model code look like:

```
//country model
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

 class Country extends Model
{
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'short_name',
    'flag_image',
    'status'
];

const STATUSES = [
    'Active' => 'Active',
    'Inactive' => 'Inactive',
];

const DEFAULT_STATUS = 'Active';
/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $timestamps = false;

public static function rules() {
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'short_name' => 'required',
        'status' => 'required|string|in:' . implode(",", Country::STATUSES)
    ];
}

 public static function saveOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    try {
        $id = $request->get('id', false);
        $country = false;
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request, &$country, $id) {

            $country = $id ? Country::findOrFail($id) : new Country();
            $country->fill($request->all());
            try {
                $country->save();
            } catch (\Exception $ex) {
                throw $ex;
            }
        });
        return $country;
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        throw $ex;
    }
} }
```

What's the problem i didn't find anything.

Comment: try `$destinationPath = '/images/admin/country/';`

Comment: is there anything else to add on app/config.php file for uploding image ?

Comment: no need to do anything